# Disable Customer Notification For New Cases

Tags: case, email2case

We are trying to use Cases in a slightly different way. I'm looking for a way to prevent the notification that is sent to the customer when a case is first created. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Isn't customer being notified of a new case turned off by default? It's a tickbox when creating Cases as far as I know....

Comment: I'm using email to case, should have mentioned that.